# Use of MOM in heterogeneous cluster system

Tags: rest, soap, mpi, cluster-computing, mom

If there is a Heterogeneous distributed clustered system , for an example let's assume about clustered server system , can we use MOM (Message Oriented Middlewear) there , if can ,can you give me some example on how it implement.

Comment: Can you be more clear ... Is there some need to transfer messages for some application? Are there different modules and web services? Is there some message flow that is identified?

Comment: let's assume a clustered application layer , there is clustered layers of ejb1 ,ejb2, ejb3 ..... and there is a clustered database system ,can we use MOM in middle of these 2 system .

Actually I'm not going to implement these systems, I'm doing a research paper on MOM for distributed heterogeneous cluster system .
I's a undergraduate independent study ...so we don't have to find new things through our research paper , just referring others research paper we have to write , so if you know any research paper related to this matter please tell 

I have to find example for this matter